# SLI video cards memory

Tags: dual-gpu

Imagine you have two identical video cards with 2GB memory **each**. I was told when they work in SLI mode, you actually have 2GB of video memory and not 4GB. Is this true and if yes - why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each card has to store the ENTIRE image so you don't get 4GB - you still only get an effective 2GB.
Upgrading to a 4GB card won't help unless they're BOTH 4GB (just thought I'd throw that out there)

Comment: Ok so it's true, but why dows every GPU need to store the whole image? Can't they work like the regular dual-channel RAM, or is it too slow to contact the other GPUs RAM?